# Разбить вектор на части

Tags: c++, vector

Разбить вектор на равные части длины n: допускается, что в конце останется часть меньшего размера. Пример: массив размера 10, его нужно разбить на блоки длины n = 3

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] -> [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10]]

Какие есть варианты разбиения с помощью встроенных функций C++? Простой проход циклом выглядит громоздко и некрасиво, особенно если последняя часть размера < n.

Comment: Предлагаю использовать [std::accumulate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate)

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: @MaximTimakov, разве accumulate не для суммы/произведения используется?

Comment: @JohnDoe с использованием функтора можно творить любую логику преобразования.

Comment: https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/blob/master/include/range/v3/view/chunk.hpp

Answer (score 2):

А можно не согласиться? [Этот код](https://ideone.com/GkfBrZ) более громоздкий и некрасивый, чем применение чего-то стандартно-алгоритмического?

```
vector<vector<int>> split(const vector<int>& v, size_t n)
{
    vector<vector<int>> r;
    for(size_t i = 0, S = v.size(), m = (S+n-1)/n; i < m; ++i)
        r.emplace_back(v.begin()+i*n,v.begin()+i*n+(i==m-1&&S%n?S%n:n));
    return r;
}
```

Для Stanislav Volodarskiy — более [обобщенный вариант](https://ideone.com/KiooWa):

```
template<typename Iterator>
vector<vector<typename Iterator::value_type>>
    split(Iterator b, Iterator e, size_t n)
{
    vector<vector<typename Iterator::value_type>> r;
    while(b != e)
    {
        Iterator start = b;               // Запомнили, откуда брать очередное
        size_t m = n;
        while(m-- && b != e) b = next(b); // Цикл или до n, или до конца
        r.emplace_back(start,b);
    }
    return r;
}
```

Comment: Со всем уважением, `v.begin()+i*n+(i==m-1&&S%n?S%n:n)` - не самая красивая конструкция.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Дело вкуса :) По сути у вас написано то же самое, только более длинно и с большим числом проверок/ветвлений. Кстати, в вашем варианте было бы лучше забыть об итераторах с произвольным доступом и работать более обобщенными средствами...

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Тогда уж такой вариант? См. дополненный ответ.

Comment: `с большим числом проверок/ветвлений` Почему?

Comment: @wololo Ну, в принципе, ладно, проверку `if (to == from)` можно и не считать, вернее, считать относящейся к циклу и не учитывать.

Comment: Обобщённый хороший. `vector<vector<int>> r;` -> `vector<vector<typename Iterator::value_type>> r;`. На выход надо push_back interator прикрутить.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy  А, ну да... Забыл исправить. А почему `push_back`, а не `emplace`?

Comment: Я имел ввиду сделать третий аргумент-итератор для записи результата в него. Как в std::copy,  например.

Answer (score 1):

Этот код громоздкий, но понятный. `from`, `to` - пара итераторов на расстоянии `n`. Когда оба итератора упираются в `end` они становятся равны, цикл прерывается:

```
vector<vector<int>> split(const vector<int> &v, size_t n) {
    const auto end = v.end();
    vector<vector<int>> result;
    auto from = v.begin();
    for (; ; ) {
        auto to = (static_cast<size_t>(end - from) > n) ? from + n : end;
        if (to == from) {
            break;
        }
        result.emplace_back(from, to);
        from = to;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Пример с `std::accumulate`:

```cpp
#include <algorythm>

using DataType = int;
using Data = std::vector<DataType>;
using Result = std::vector<Data>;


Data data;
size_t slice_sz = 3;
auto result = std::accumulate(data.begin() data.end(), Result{}, [slice_sz](Result r, DataType d) -> Result
{
    if (r.empty() || r.back().size() == slice_sz)
    {
        r.emplace_back();
        r.back().reserve(slice_sz);
    }
    
    r.back().emplace_back(d);
    
    return r;
});
```

За работоспособность не отвечаю - писал на коленке - но идея должна быть понятна.

Comment: Такое ощущение, что `accumulate` играет роль просто цикла. С тем же успехом можно использовать `foreach`?